# How to support 64-bit times on a 32-bit Linux platform

Tags: linux, kernel, time

I need to support 64-bit times on a 32-bit ARM embedded Linux system based on kernel version 4.1.

I use clock_gettime() and clock_settime() to get/set the time, but they are limited to 32-bit seconds values currently, which results in a year-2038 problem, which is an issue for this system.

After researching this a bit, it seems that the solution is to get the kernel to use struct timespec64 internally. Userland will then continue to use struct timespec, but its tv_sec member will be 64-bits.

My question is, how does one enable this change to use the 64-bit timespec in the kernel?

According to Jonathan Corbet's article [System call conversion for year 2038](https://lwn.net/Articles/643234), the first step toward this goal involves setting the CONFIG_COMPAT_TIME symbol, but I've grepped my kernel source for that symbol and it doesn't appear anywhere. At this point I'm wondering if 64-bit
timespec support is still only partially implemented, or if its implementation has changed direction since that article was written.